# Adjetivo equivalente à locução adverbial "sem flores"

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, adjetivos

Estou vendo um vídeo na internet e o professor (ele é professor mesmo) disse que não há adjetivo significando “sem flores”. Não seria *desflorido*?

Comment: No VOLP, há a palavra: *desflorescido*. De acordo com o *dicio.com.br*, esse termo significa *"Deixar de possuir floração; perder as flores"*.

Comment: Diego, procuraste pelo menos no dicionário? O que encontraste? A que conclusões chegaste?